# Dynamically Insert and Retriev the key value pair from array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to insert dynamic Key and values into array object in the html page.

```
    var answers=[];

    $(".btn-like, .btn-dislike").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.text();
        var inter_data_type = $this.parent().attr('id');

          if(!inter_data_type in answers) {
            answers.push({"inter_data_type":value});
          }
         alert(answers); //displaying [object][object]
         alert(answers.inter_data_type); // displaying undefined
    });
```

Need to check whether key is exists in array or not before insert it, if key and value are present then no need to insert it, if the key is same and value is different then need to replace the value for particular key. but above code not working.
Even though if it inserts into array not able to get the value.

Comment: If you are going to use n no of obj use forEach or map,keys to retrieve values.

Comment: I reckon OP is looking for dynamic `key` and `value`

Comment: `answers` is an Array. You are pushing an Object onto an Array. Think about it, you would need to access the Array element first.

Comment: Your code is not working first because of the error in if statement and secondly on the last line, "the way you are accessing the array". Just have a look at edited answer below to find the corrections.

Comment: If use a map instead of array we can achieve this.   var answers={}; answers[inter_data_type]=value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use a map instead of array we can achieve this.

```
var answers={}; 
answers[inter_data_type]=value;
```

Answer (score 1):

try `alert(answers[0].inter_data_type)`
answers is an array so you have to say which element you are interested in. You do it by providing numeric index.

I would suggest to use for better visualisation

```
console.debug(answers);
```

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
answers.push({"inter_data_type":"value"});

alert(answers[0].inter_data_type); // displaying undefined
```

Comment: you can refer : [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

you are inserting data in Array using key value pair it's JSON. so if you want to get it in alert so you have to do like this and also check key or value is exists or not.

Hope it will helpful for you. Enjoy coding..!!

```
var answers=[];
var value = $this.text();
var inter_data_type = $this.parent().attr('id');

for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
    if(answers.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        for(var prop in answers[i]){ // For get Key
            if(answers[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                if(answers[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) == inter_data_type){ //For check key is same or not
                    if(answers[i][inter_data_type] != value){ // For check value is same or not
                        answers[i][inter_data_type] = value;  // replace value if not same
                    }else{

                    }
                }else{
                    answers.push({inter_data_type:value});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(answers));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your question and realized that you ask for something else than I originally thought.
But try this:

```
var  answers=[];
    var value = $this.text();
    var inter_data_type = $this.parent().attr('id');
    var isThere = false;
    for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++)
    {
        if(answers[i].inter_data_type==inter_data_type)
        {isThere=true;break;}
    }

    if(isThere===true){
       answers.push({inter_data_type:inter_data_type, value:value});
     }        
    console.debug(answers);
    console.debug(answers[0].inter_data_type,answers[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
var answerMap = [];
if (answerMap["key_name"] == undefined) {
    answerMap["key_name"] = value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the edit made to the question and expecting that the question expects dynamic key, dynamic value and also the "if" statement checks the dynamic value of inter_data_type in answers. Following is the working script.

```
var answers=[];

$(".btn-like, .btn-dislike").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.text();
    var inter_data_type = $this.parent().attr('id');

      if(!(inter_data_type in answers)) {   // Please note the extra brackets used here
        answers[inter_data_type] = value;
      }
     alert(answers); // It will display ["Some inter data": "Some Val"]
     alert(answers[inter_data_type]); // It will display "Some val"
});
```

Comment: The code as you have it mixes between using a variable for the key and a static string. Line 1 checks if the variable key exists. Line 2 sets a static key value using bracket notation. Line 5 uses a static key with dot notation. Also, treats an array like an object, which isn't how you're supposed to use arrays.

Comment: In the question itself the key is static and is being accessed using static key only. Thats why said "If you want to access the array the same way..."

Comment: Have made the edit, Assuming that the question expects dynamic key, dynamic value and also the "if" statement checks the dynamic value of inter_data_type in answers. I guess this is the intention behind the question.